# xflux and systemd on Debian jessie

Tags: debian, x11, kde-plasma, systemd

I`m trying to add xflux as systemd service, so that it launches on startup, but when I use

```
# systemctl start xflux.service
```

it fails to start. My xflux.service unit looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=xflux loader
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xflux -l 17
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

I`ve tried to express ExecStart on various ways, like

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/xflux -l 17"
```

or

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/start-xflux
```

'start-flux' being a sh script with a line:

```
exec /usr/bin/xflux -l 17
```

Nothing worked. I always get the same prompt from 'systemctl status':

```
● xflux.service - xflux loader
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/xflux.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since śro 2016-03-09 21:53:47 CET; 43min ago
 Main PID: 4409 (code=exited, status=255)

mar 09 21:53:47 debian systemd[1]: Unit xflux.service entered failed state.
mar 09 21:53:47 debian xflux[4561]: [10B blob data]
mar 09 21:53:47 debian xflux[4561]: --------
mar 09 21:53:47 debian xflux[4561]: Welcome to xflux (f.lux for X)
mar 09 21:53:47 debian xflux[4561]: This will only work if you're running X on console.
mar 09 21:53:47 debian xflux[4561]: Guessing your longitude is 15.0 based on your timezone
mar 09 21:53:47 debian xflux[4561]: Specify it with -g to make things better.
mar 09 21:53:47 debian systemd[1]: xflux.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
mar 09 21:53:47 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start xflux loader.
mar 09 21:53:47 debian systemd[1]: Unit xflux.service entered failed state.
```

I also tried [auto-xflux](https://github.com/jamesan/auto-xflux) - without success. I obviously don`t understand something either about xflux (what does "https://github.com/jamesan/auto-xflux" prompt mean?) or systemd. 
I should also add that calling

```
$ xflux -l 17
```

from a terminal works just fine.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add

```
[Service] 
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
```

(or whatever your `DISPLAY` number is, check it with `echo $DISPLAY` from a shell running under an X session).  Also, you probably want to running this under your user instance of systemd instead of the system instance, i.e. use `systemctl --user start xflux.service` and put the unit in `~/.config/systemd/user/xflux.service`.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#DISPLAY_and_XAUTHORITY